# Hibernate mapping missing column error

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am using hibernate mapping in a project in Java and I have an error that I cannot figured out. I have several tables that includes column names all in lower case (e.g. db_id). To use them in Java, in my .hbm.xml file I am mapping them with the following line:

```
<id name="dbId" type="long" column="DB_ID">
```

I haven't got any error until now. Even if I use upper case above (column="DB_ID"), mapping was successfull. However, I now get a missing column error when I try running the project. The error line is like:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: DB_ID in public.x.account
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:277)
```

When I change the column name from db_id to DB_ID manually in pgAdmin or Navicat(I am using PostgreSQL), this error disappears and the next column name gives error. I have tens of tables and hundreds of column names. I have also many .hbm.xml files for mapping. (This is a part of a big project.) So I do not want to change all column names manually or change the all column attributes in .hbm.xml files.

How can I make hibernate mapping case insensitive? Even if I use column="DB_ID" in my .hbm.xml file, I want my db_id column to be recognized in mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.

I guess the issue stems from the fact that the language of the operating system or java is not set in English. So I created a setenv.bat file in the apache-tomcat/bin directory and fill it with the following statement

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US
```

It is solved with this way. I hope this will be helpful for the people who are experiencing the same issue.